# How can I fix No Agent definition found for id Watson Assistant error?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

The problem is about creating an app that uses Watson chatbot.

Well, I used Vidyasagar Machupalli code the app worked but the part of chatbot didn't. Here is the logcat error:

```
(2019-04-28 07:36:02.927 4315-4372/com.example.vmac.chatbot D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/81d0c0e2-5c74-45c6-9f3b-63bcf1b0b281/sessions?version=2018-11-08 (662ms, 105-byte body)
2019-04-28 07:36:02.966 4315-4372/com.example.vmac.chatbot E/WatsonService: POST https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/81d0c0e2-5c74-45c6-9f3b-63bcf1b0b281/sessions?version=2018-11-08, status: 404, error: NotFound: No Agent definition found for id: 81d0c0e2-5c74-45c6-9f3b-63bcf1b0b281
2019-04-28 07:36:02.974 4315-4372/com.example.vmac.chatbot W/System.err: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.NotFoundException: NotFound: No Agent definition found for id: 81d0c0e2-5c74-45c6-9f3b-63bcf1b0b281)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!--Watson Assistant service credentials-->
<!-- REPLACE `ASSISTANT_ID_HERE` with ID of the Assistant to use -->
<string name="assistant_id">####################################</string>


<!-- REPLACE `ASSISTANT_API_KEY_HERE` with Watson Assistant service API Key-->
<string name="assistant_apikey">##################################</string>

<!-- REPLACE `ASSISTANT_URL_HERE` with Watson Assistant service URL-->
<string name="assistant_url">https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api</string>


<!--Watson Speech To Text(STT) service credentials-->
<!-- REPLACE `STT_API_KEY_HERE` with Watson Speech to Text service API Key-->
<string name="STT_apikey">#############################</string>

<!-- REPLACE `STT_URL_HERE` with Watson Speech to Text service URL-->
<string name="STT_url">https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api</string>


<!--Watson Text To Speech(TTS) service credentials-->
<!-- REPLACE `TTS_API_KEY_HERE` with Watson Text to Speech service API Key-->
<string name="TTS_apikey">############################</string>

<!-- REPLACE `TTS_URL_HERE` with Watson Text to Speech service URL-->
<string name="TTS_url">https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api</string>d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the error is instead of **Assistant ID** you are passing `Skill ID` in your config.xml. Create an Assistant using the Skill you created and pass the **Assistant ID** in the config.xml

Here's how you can [link your Skill to an Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-android-watson-chatbot#link-the-skill-to-an-assistant)

> Also. never share your credentials in public forums.

**Updated**: Here's where you can find your **Assistant ID** by clicking Settings as shown in the image below and then `API Details`
[image]

Comment: ok thank you but the app is not showing the option and my bot is totaly made of it is there any solution ?

Comment: Updated my answer above. Nope your workspace ID is not Assistant ID

Comment: yeah thanks to you is there any solution to show the bot options ? the app only shows text

Comment: What do you mean by bot options? Can you elaborate?

Comment: well when i run the app, only text can be send from watson the option do not appear in the app

Comment: if i make option in watson assitant they do not appear in the android app only text do

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand. Can you post a screenshot of what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the screenshot are avaible on my answer link